# Laravel migration infinite loop

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have a custom migration command below

```
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand as BaseMigrateCommand;

class MigrateAllCustomersCommand extends BaseMigrateCommand
{
    private $count = 0;
    public function __construct(Migrator $migrator)
    {
       parent::__construct($migrator);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->count += 1;
        printf("%d,",$this->count);
        $this->call('migrate');
    }
}
```

`php artisan migrate` runs infinitely as show in the following output: `1,2,3,...,10000...`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What laravel version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This makes your migration being called recursively, causing the infinite loop.

```
$this->call('migrate');
```

If you intended to call the parent's class behavior, then what you actually wanted is

```
parent::handle();
```

#### Bonus

Here's a tutorial on [extending custom migration commands](https://hackernoon.com/extending-laravels-migration-command-to-add-new-options-90b5a0fc4ef4).

Comment: How do I specify the migration folder if using `parent::handle()`

Comment: How do I set `--path` and other options with `parent::handle()`?